# How do I display values stored in the dl register using NASM (assembly)?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm fairly new to assembly, so let me know if this question is too ambiguous to answer, or if I need to include more information.

Basically, I have some information stored in the `dl` register. The `eax`, `ebx`, and `ecx` registers also have values stored in them that I want to keep. How do I display the `dl` register to the screen without changing the values of the other registers?

I've also tried used `int 21h`, but I'm getting segmentation faults while using that.

Comment: DOS, Windows, Linux, something else?

Answer (score 0):

The environment you're working under will determine how you can display what you're trying to display. The `int 21h` interrupts are a DOS service, and so will not be available unless you're working in a DOS environment (eg in a pure BIOS environment without DOS loaded). If this is the case you should look at the [`int 10h` video services](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-10.htm) - for example [`int 10h AX=0Ah`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0100.htm).

As far as retaining the values of the other registers - this will depend on how you choose to display your output. The `int 10h AX=0Ah` service I mention above requires use of the `AH`, `AH`, `BH`, `BL` and `CX` registers - to use this service you would have to move your values from the `EAX`, `EBX` and `ECX` registers elsewhere - perhaps by moving to other registers, storing them to specific memory locations, or by setting up a stack and `PUSH`ing, then `POP`ing the values back into the registers after displaying your value.